# How to find minimum in a row with variable columns python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying below:

```
df ['best_rate'] = df.loc [ df [[ 'a', 'b', 'c', ..... , 'z' ]] ].min(axis=1)
```

where `a`, `b`, `c` ,..., `z` are columns in the `df`.

Now, because of some previous statements , some of these columns would not be available when I am trying to find the minimum. Basically these columns would have  been dropped out as I would have applied dropna(). But which column gets dropped out depends on the data set.

Now , I am to find minimum after some columns have been dropped out. I don't know which columns have been dropped out. But I know new set of columns would be a subset of the columns before I dropped the columns. So how do I ignore those columns that have been dropped when trying to find the minimum?

If I use:

```
df ['best_rate'] = df.loc [ df [[ 'a', 'b', 'c', ..... , 'z' ]] ].min(axis=1)
```

I get error: `column 'x' not in index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
df['best_rate'] = df.loc[:, set([ 'a', 'b', 'c', ..... , 'z' ]) & set(df.columns)].min(axis=1)
```

It uses set intersect to find common columns between your pre-defined list and existing columns.